# How to download older version of magento

Tags: magento, download, version

I want to download older version  (1.7) of magento.

1. I could not find any zip/tar file on magentocommerce.com for version 1.7.x
2. I tried with downloader but it downloads latest version instead of 1.7.x.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

goto below link

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/download
```

And then click on `Release Archives tab` and here you will find old magento version

Comment: No direct download anymore?

Comment: updated link: https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

Answer (score 3):

You can find here a list of magento version going back to 1.1:
https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/

Or what @AmitBera said.

Answer (score 1):

Download all version of magento 2.

**Url : https://github.com/magento/magento2/releases**